# how to choose parameters in TfidfVectorizer in sklearn during unsupervised clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

TfidfVectorizer provides an easy way to encode & transform texts into vectors.

My question is how to choose the proper values for parameters such as min_df, max_features, smooth_idf, sublinear_tf?

update:

Maybe I should have put more details on the question:

What if I am doing unsupervised clustering with bunch of texts. and I don't have any labels for the texts & I don't know how many clusters there might be (which is actually what I am trying to figure out)

Comment: Look into "cross-validation". That decision process is called "hyperparameter tuning" because `min_df`, etc. are hyperparameters.

Answer (score 16):

If you are, for instance, using these vectors in a classification task, you can vary these parameters (and of course also the parameters of the classifier) and see which values give you the best performance.

You can do that in sklearn easily with the GridSearchCV and Pipeline objects

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB(
        fit_prior=True, class_prior=None))),
])
parameters = {
    'tfidf__max_df': (0.25, 0.5, 0.75),
    'tfidf__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
    'clf__estimator__alpha': (1e-2, 1e-3)
}

grid_search_tune = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=2, n_jobs=2, verbose=3)
grid_search_tune.fit(train_x, train_y)

print("Best parameters set:")
print grid_search_tune.best_estimator_.steps
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Unfortunately, I am doing unsupervised clustering with a set of texts. and I don't even have any labels for possible clusters. what should I do?

Comment: You can evaluate how good your clusters are, for instance: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cluster_analysis#/Evaluation_and_assessment, and check how the TfIdfVectorizer parameters also influence the results